# $C^\infty$ functions with all derivatives in $L^p$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, sobolev-spaces

Let $1\le p<\infty$ and $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ be such that its all derivatives $f^{(n)} \in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ for every $n\in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$. 
Is it true that $f\in L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$?
If it is true, do we have a generalization in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

My partial answer for $p=1$:

For $p=1$ and  $t\in \mathbb{R}$, we have
$$
|g(t)|=
|\int_{0}^{t} g'(x) \ dx+g(0)|
\le
\int_{0}^{t}
|g'(x)| \ dx
+|g(0)|
\le 
\|g'\|_{L^1}
+|g(0)|.
$$ 
Thus, $g\in L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ with 
$\|g\|_{L^\infty} \le \|g'\|_{L^1}+|g(0)|$.

Thanks for help and hint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That $f'\in L^1(\mathbb R)$ implies already that $f \in L^\infty$. To see this, first we observe that 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 0.$$
Indeed like you did, 
$$f(x) - f(y) = \int_x^y f'(s) ds\Rightarrow |f(x) - f(y)| \le \int_x^y |f'(s)|ds \to 0$$
as $x, y\to \infty$ (this is where we use $f' \in L^1$). Thus $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)$ exists and must be zero since $f\in L^1$. Then

$$f(x) = \int_\infty^x f'(s)ds\Rightarrow |f(x)| \le \|f'\|_{L^1}.$$

When $p>1$, we consider $g = f^p$. Then $g' = pf^{p-1} f'$ and so by Holder's inequality

$$\begin{split} \int |g'| &= p \int |f^{p-1} f'|  \\
& \le p \left(\int |f^{p-1}|^{\frac{p}{p-1}}\right)^{1-1/p} \left(\int |f'|^p\right)^{1/p}\\
&= p \| f\|_{L^p}^{p-1} \| f'\|_{L^p}
\end{split}$$

Thus $g$ satisfies $g,g' \in L^1$ and so $g\in L^\infty$ by the first argument. Hence $f\in L^\infty$.

The generalization in $\mathbb R^n$ is the general [Sobolev embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality#Sobolev_embedding_theorem), which shows that your $f$ has pointwise bounds on all derivatives
$$ \sup_{x\in \mathbb R^n} |D_I f(x)| \le C(I,f) <\infty.$$

Comment: Shouldn't there be a minus sign in front of that last integral?

Comment: @tomasz : Thanks, edited.

Comment: @JohnMa: Maybe power ``1/p" is missing. I am sorry if it is too elementary, How do we conclude $f\in L^\infty$ from $f$ is Holder continuous?

Comment: @testes Thanks for pointing that out. The argument was not quite correct. Please see the edit.

Comment: @JohnMa: I see the reason now. Is it alright if we assume that $f\ge 0$? Because you define $g=f^p$.

Comment: Good point again (since you tag "sobolev space" I should have include that in the answer). The point is that $|f|$ is also almost everywhere differentiable and $|f|' = \pm f'$ almost everywhere. Thus we can consider $|f|$ instead of $f$ @testes

Comment: The last bit seems a little fuzzy to me. In fact $|f|$ is differentiable everywhere except for a countable set. With your approach I would think absolute continuity would play a role. I took a slightly different route in my answer.

Comment: @JohnMa: After reading Sobolev embedding, I think that the function will be in L^{p*} where $p<p*<\infty$. But I can not find the argument $f\in L^\infty$.

Comment: There are two versions of sobolev embedding, one for $kp<n$ and one for $kp>n$. If you use the latter case, since $f^{(k)} \in L^p$ for all $k$, choose $kp >n$ and so it embeds into Holder spaces @testes

Answer (score 3):

If $f\in C^1$ and $f' \in L^1,$ then

$$|f(x)-f(0)| = |\int_0^x f'| \le \|f'\|_1,$$

giving $\|f\|_\infty \le |f(0)| + \|f'\|_1.$

Suppose $p>1.$ If $f\in C^1,$ then $|f|^p$ is the composition of $|x|^p \in C^1$ with $f;$ hence $|f|^p\in C^1.$ Check that the formula $(|f|^p)'(x) = p|f|^{p-1}f'(x)\text { sgn }(f(x))$ holds. If we assume now that $f, f'\in L^p,$ then we know $|f|^{p-1}f' \in L^1$ as in John Ma's answer. By the first paragraph, we have $|f|^p,$ and hence $f,$ in $L^\infty.$

Comment: Thank you for adding your answer. Do you know whether we have a generalization in $R^n$? After reading about Sobolev embedding, the case $p>n$ and bounded domain is true. Do we still have $f\in L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$?